# The php file is download instead execute on nginx

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, configuration

I use the `Symfony` config of `Nginx` server:

```
server {
    server_name cmf.localhost www.cmf.localhost;
    root /mnt/hgfs/www/cmf/web;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/cmf.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/cmf.access.log;

    # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
    rewrite ^/app_dev\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location = /libs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    location / {
        index app_dev.php app.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php/$1 last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server from upstream phpfcgi
    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

and it work well, but I also need to execute `/libs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php`. Now when I try to execute them, it simply  download.

How can I config Nginx to executed `/libs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php` file?

Comment: @saurav What exactly line are you meant?

Comment: My config is right, I need to clear browser cache only

Answer (score -1):

```
server {
        listen   80;


        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

}
```

Comment: Is this example adapted to Symfony Framework? Or you simply copy/paste your own config? )

Comment: But your config is broken Symfony!

Comment: My config was right, I need to clear browser cache only